# Is it possible to play Just Dance 2014 using a smartphone?

Tags: ps4, just-dance-2014

I currently have *Just Dance 2014*. However, we realized that we didn't have a PlayStation Camera.

I understand that you can set up *Just Dance 2017* with the smartphone by installing some app (is it the *Just Dance* controller app?) but will that also work for the 2014 version?

Comment: This question has a [Meta Discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12726/28182) please contribute your thoughts there.

Answer (score 22):

I just tried installing the *Just Dance* controller app on my Android smartphone. It was a pretty straightforward process. It asked for the console (available are PS4, Xbox One, PC) and the versions (2017 up to 2015).

Upon finding out that the 2014 version isn't included, I clicked on the "?" button. It then said

> Sorry but this application does not support other versions of Just Dance.

So there.